# How to select an attribute by a variable in xquery?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, saxon, xquery-3.0

I know how to select an attribute like so:

```
$table/@id
```

However how do I do this if the attribute name is stored as a variable. For example:

```
let $x = "id"
$table/@[$x]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the functions `local-name` or `node-name` to capture the value of the attribute and match it the predicate. `local-name` will simply return a string that matches the element name, and `node-name` will return a fully qualified name, which is generally recommended, but practically speaking, is only necessary if you are dealing with namespaces.

```
let $x = "id"
return $table/@*[local-name(.) = $x]

let $x := xs:QName("id")
return $table/@*[node-name(.) = $x]
```

Comment: Great! How could this be expanded to deal with variable elements? for example `$table/$x`

Comment: For example: `let $x := "foo" return $table/$x`

Comment: Made it to a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026352/how-to-select-an-element-by-a-variable-in-xquery