# How to select an element by a variable in xquery?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xquery-3.0

I know how to select an element like so:

```
$table/foo
```

However how do I do this if the element name is stored as a variable. For example:

```
let $x = "foo"
$table/[$x]
```

I know how do this if it was a property from:
[How to select an attribute by a variable in xquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025758/how-to-select-an-attribute-by-a-variable-in-xquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nearly identical to the answer for the question [How to select an attribute by a variable in xquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025758/how-to-select-an-attribute-by-a-variable-in-xquery/34025946#34025946) but instead of using the attribute selector `@*`, you would use the element selector, `*` (or `element()`):

```
$table/*[local-name() = 'foo']

$table/element()[local-name() = 'foo']
```

Comment: which is more likely to be more efficient `*` or `element()`

Comment: @YahyaUddin They are equivalent. You can think of `*` as a "macro" for `element()`.

Comment: Would this still work if the element name was more complex like "foo/bar/hat"

Comment: @YahyaUddin Yes, in every case these are essentially just evaluating expressions and subexpressions. Similar to the star expression, `foo/bar` is shorthand for `element(foo)/child::element(bar)`. You can continue to walk the tree indefinitely as long as your expressions are valid.

Answer (score 1):

> Would this still work if the element name was more complex like "foo/bar/hat"

No, the predicate `[name() = 'foo/bar/hat']` would not select anything, because `foo/bar/hat` is a path expression, not an element name. Variables in XPath hold values, not expressions or expression fragments - it's not like a shellscript (or other macro language) where variables are expanded and the expanded expression is then re-parsed.

XQuery does not have any general capability for constructing an expression dynamically as a string and then evaluating it. Many products have extension functions to do this, often called xx:eval() or xx:evaluate(). XSLT 3.0 has an xsl:evaluate instruction.

Comment: I have rolled back the edits. That kind of typography might look good in Chennai, but it's not my style, and I reserve the right to write in my own style without some copy-editor changing it to suit theirs.